# Разбиение строки php

Tags: php, строки

Помогите пожалуйста.

Вот например есть строка: `"0 Text Numbers Mes"`
Можно функцией `list` разбить на отдельные элементы, вроде этого `list($id, $text, $Num, $mes)=$arr` и затем использовать переменные. А вот если текст повторяется, например:`"0 Text Numbers Mes 1 Text1 Numbers1 Mes1 2 Text2 Numbers2 Mes2"` и т.д., то есть сделать что-то вроде таблицы со столбиками `id, text` и т.д. Можно ли это также разбить функцией `list`, или есть какие то другие?

Comment: Так себе вариант, но всё же: [`ideone.com`][1]

[1]: http://ideone.com/fjhfPM

Comment: Спасибо за решение. Только вот у меня не получается перенос строки.

Comment: Сделал вместо \n <br>, все получилось. Я как понимаю, вот эта часть "if($i%4==0)" отвечает за количество колонок?

Comment: @dizznt, HTML не отображает `\n` как переводы строк, иногда только в верстке появляется в виде пустого текстнода. % - оператор получения остатка от деления, таким образом действие в if будет происходить на каждой четвертой строке.

Comment: Спасибо всем за помощь. Так, а если мне надо определенные элементы достать,например только $id и $num. Нужно разбить list? И работать с нужными переменными.

Comment: @dizznt, с чем удобнее - способов перенести данные из одной переменной в другую миллиарды. Скажу только, что "получить все", а потом использовать только необходимую часть - это нормальная практика, становящаяся нежелательной только на нагруженных проектах.  
Мне кажется, тут присутствует [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/66378), возможно, было бы проще подсказать, если бы вы описали, чего пытаетесь достичь.

Comment: Я хочу разбить текст из файла, он идет подряд, через разделитель пробелы, строки которого похожи. Дальше я хочу разбить строки на переменные, и в дальнейшем вывести нужные мне.
@Fike спасибо, буду пробовать, изучать.

Comment: @dizznt, мне просто кажется, что база данных здесь бы больше подошла.  
Проще всего любым из предложенных способов получить **все** данные, получится двумерный массив (массив из массивов значений строки). После этого с помощью foreach пройтись по всем данным и вывести. Вот пример вывода таблицей [всего подряд](http://ideone.com/q8At6Q) и только [первого и третьего элемента](http://ideone.com/PJBoUf).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если у вас есть разделитель, который явно отделяет отдну строку от другой (нпример, символ перевода строки):

```
$lines = explode("\n", $text);
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    // работаем с каждой строкой по отдельности
}
```

Если есть неявный разделитель (пробел, который делит слова), то проще всего будет решение от [[@ua6xh](/users/14126/ua6xh)](/users/14126/ua6xh).
Если разделителя нет (или он опять неявный), то можно разбивать регулярными выражениями (что по сути правильно, просто регулярные выражения могут отъедать больше ресурсов, чем простая работа со строками):

```
preg_match_all('#(\d+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)#mu', $text, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
// в массиве $matches уже будут находится по массиву на каждое совпадение шаблона, где 0 - полное совпадение шаблона, а начиная с 1 - те данные, которые нужны.
```